# Permission denied for echo ‘{file}’ > path/file.dat even when logged in as a user with appropriate permissions

Tags: python, linux, bash, fabric

I’m writing a Python script to log into a remote Linux server (dev) as an admin user, then:

1. creating a backup of a file in a directory called Archive

   ```
   dev.sudo(“bash -c ‘cd /path/; cp file.dat Archive/file.dat)
   ```
2. Reading the file and saving as variable

   ```
   read_file = dev.sudo(“bash -c ‘cd /path/; cat file.dat)
   ```
3. I’m then inserting a new value into the file and want to overwrite the existing file on my server

   ```
   dev.sudo(f”echo ‘{new_file}’ > /path/file.dat)
   ```

   However this final step is returning a ‘Permission denied’ error. The user I’m logged in as has the appropriate permissions, and this works if I was to manually perform this step on the command line in the server.

I’m not sure what could be causing this permission error.

I’m using the fabric library, for further info.

I’ve tried running the command in bash -c with no further luck.

I have confirmed the backup has been made successfully and I added a print(new_file) to ensure the correct thing is being fed into the server.

Comment: Exactly what commands did you try? When you combine sudo and redirection (eg. `>` and `>>`) you can end up with nasty gotchas. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683819/sudo-redirection-permission-denied

Comment: Please check your quotes. Don't use curly qoutes, and most times use them in pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Using sudo and output redirection can result in unexpected outcomes. Namely only the bit before the `>` is executed as the sudo-ed user, whereas the bit after the `>` is done as the user that issued the sudo command.

So when you do:

```
sudo echo foo > out.txt
```

Only `echo foo` is executed as `root`. But the collection of the output of `sudo` (and therefore `echo`) and saving it to a file is done as an unprivileged user.

For example:

```
dunes@lp:~/test$ ls -l  # empty dir, no files
total 0
dunes@lp:~/test$ sudo echo foo > user.txt  # file will be owned by ordinary user
dunes@lp:~/test$ sudo bash -c 'echo foo > root.txt'  # file will be owned by root
dunes@lp:~/test$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root     4 Nov 21 14:08 root.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 dunes dunes    4 Nov 21 14:08 user.txt
```

So if `/path/file.dat` already exists and is owned by another user / root, then the user you are logged in as will not be able to modify the file*.
As you can see in the example, the answer is to encase the **entire** line in `bash -c`.

* unless the file has write permissions for other (and/or group and you are in that group).

Answer (score 0):

Check your file permissions. You get a similar error after

```
touch /tmp/acz
chmod 444 /tmp/acz
echo "Something" > /tmp/acz
# Returns
-bash: /tmp/acz: Permission denied
```

It looks like the file or directory is protected against writing. Please try `echo '{new_file}' > /path/file.dat` from the bash command line.